# Add some sort of feed back mechanism on the job descriptions in Careers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, jobs, voting

Some of the jobs descriptions and formatting in Careers are...not exactly optimal.  StackOverflow has a fantastic system for educating folks on better ways of asking and formatting questions.  Maybe Careers could introduce some sort of feedback mechanism for the job postings?  Here is an example of two mildly similar jobs from two different employeers:

- [Well formatted, clear, thoughtful](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/11858/program-manager-surround-technologies)
- [Copy-paste, poor formatting, *PLZ SEND TEH L33T CODERZ*](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/11965/project-manager-professional-everyday-health)

  **edit**: I (Korneel) cleaned this listing up

Obviously, edits are out of the quesiton.  But what about comments or votes?  They do not necessarily be visible to the entire world--just the submitter and the employer.

The intended result of all this would be higher quality job postings by employers.  And a win-win for everyone.

Comment: +1 - I frequently see typoes in job ads, but it doesn't always feel right to report them - neither to careers.SE, nor to the poster. A simple feedback button would fix that.

Comment: And +1 for `PLZ SEND TEH L33T CODERZ.`

Comment: @Pekka - If you misspell "typos", is it like dividing by zero? You've doomed us all!

Comment: Wow, that second one scored 13/12 on the Joel Test. I thought the only way to do that was to be actually owned by Joel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this listing to our attention! We've wanted to implement a feedback / flagging mechanism for a while now but haven't gotten around to yet (no solid ETA yet). I really like the idea of it not being publicly visible, but more of a quality indicator to both the employer posting and us. I'll update this answer once we have a more concrete sense of when we would implement this.

PS: I went ahead and fixed that listing...

Answer (score 3):

We've implemented a "Flag a problem" link on the right-hand side of job listings. You do need to be logged into Careers to see it. Hope this helps.